# chart.js v2 setting the y scale options seem to getting ignored

Tags: javascript, chart.js, angular-chart

I'm trying to set my bar chart's y scale so that it shows ticks from 0-100 every 20. However, it does not seem to respecting my options.

My options look like this:

```
this.options = {
  scales: {
    yAxis: [{
      display: true,
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        stepSize: 20
       }
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: What chart type is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's Axes not Axis:

```
this.options = {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      display: true,
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        stepSize: 20
       }
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Omg I feel so dumb. Thank you.

Comment: @user2734679 this happens to everyone. Hardest bugs to find are tiny spelling mistakes :-)